# Convert Numeric type 2000.50 to 2000/09/30 data format in powerbi

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm trying to convert numeric column which have values as  2000.50/2000.75 and to date format as 2000/09/30 in PowerBI

```
VAR FiscalYear2 =
    LEFT ( Axio_QuarterlySupplyDemandModelNational[Year_Dup], 4 )
RETURN
    (
        SWITCH (
            RIGHT ( Axio_QuarterlySupplyDemandModelNational[Year_Dup], 3),
            ".00", "3/31/" & FiscalYear2,
            ".25", "6/30/" & FiscalYear2,
            ".50", "9/30/" & FiscalYear2,
            ".75", "12/31/" & FiscalYear2     
        )
)
```

I tried the attached code, but some of the values such as 2000.00/2000.50 are not converted as expected.

Comment: I would suggest you handle data conversion in PowerQuery ie.when loading data.

Comment: I tested your scenario and it worked fine. I ensured the column Axio_QuarterlySupplyDemandModelNational[Year_Dup] is a text field (not number)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But, Whenever I convert the column into text, 2000.00 is getting converted into 2000 and similarly for 2000.50 into 2000.5.

Comment: How much control do you have over your model?  If you have (and you should) a date table, then I would add a column with these 'decimal id' numbers to the date table and create a relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few approaches that I would think are better than trying to transform the decimal date value in DAX.  In the comments, it's been recommended that you do your conversion in Power Query, which is a great suggestion, or use a date table.

We don't always have control over the model tho, so if an additional column on the reporting side is needed, I would suggest that this isn't a formatting question.  Fractional years are not a standard date format.  You have numbers, so your approach should not be to parse or format, but to calculate.

```
DateConverted_col = 
    VAR YearVal = TRUNC(Axio_QuarterlySupplyDemandModelNational[Year_Dup])
    VAR QuarterVal = Mod(Axio_QuarterlySupplyDemandModelNational[Year_Dup] * 4, 4) + 1

    RETURN Date(YearVal, QuarterVal * 3 + 1, 1) - 1
```

The TRUNC function drops the decimal portion of the number, leaving you with just the year.

Modulo needs a little massage for fractional numbers.  Scaling up by 4 and then finding mod 4 will give you a 0-3 value.  Add one and that's the Quarter we're working with.

Multiply the quarter by 3 to get the month number.  Figure out that month's last day by adding a whole month to its first day, and then subtracting a single day.  Presto, you have the last day of the quarter.

Hope it helps.